# hypoid gears described mathematically

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, reference-request

I bought a worm drive electric saw recently. The claim is that, rather than the worm drive I expected, the drive involves [hypoid gears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_bevel_gear#Hypoid_gears). From what I can see, hypoid is an abbreviation of hyperboloid. The claim is that the "envelope" of the teeth is a hyperboloid of revolution. Also that the teeth (the outer edges, I guess) are helical. At this point I don't know which gear they are talking about, a drive is two gears.

I do have some engineering books from my father, but I can't find anything on this. Gear manufacture books seem to be insanely expensive. I suspect there is no Gear Manufacture for Dummies.

Does anyone know the mathematics of this?

I see the picture below as possibly a hyperboloid of two sheets for the large gear,  <strike>one sheet</strike> matching two sheets for the small gear.
It is just that the small one is from the other side.  The part about helices might be true. The design goes back to the same Hero of Alexandria responsible for  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula according to Pliny the Elder. He credits Hero with the nut and bolt (in wood) and the first worm drive.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Good_Turn_(book)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witold_Rybczynski

[image]

Pictures below are from the 3-D printing website that Jean Marie found.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Will. I didn't know that hyperboloids with two sheets were used for gears. No idea at present to "the mathematics behind"... Here is a site connected with 3D printing of many of these gears: http://www.otvinta.com/download06.html

Comment: Here is a relevant reference: "A Mathematical Model for the tooth Geometry of Hypoid gears" by Tsay and Liu, Math. Comput. Modeling Vol 18 n°2 p. 23-34, 1993: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/089571779390004I

Comment: @JeanMarie  Thank you! As to 3-D printing, my father had a few gear models at home; he was an electrical engineer, but the geometry of physical systems also mattered. I would enjoy having a model of some sort.

Comment: They let me download Tsay-Lin as a pdf. I love the detail of the "pinion" teeth, Figure 5.

Comment: This [article](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/7e6024e92f796d73f162a2fca8ee4eaa/vtgu587.pdf) (unfortunately in Russian) has simple explanations for hypoid gears but with hyperboloids with one sheet. I just found by the same author [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318321679_Tangency_of_one-sheeted_hyperboloids_as_axoids_of_the_hypoid_gearing).

Comment: @JeanMarie I think I will send your Russian link to my friend Dmitry in Texas; also the English ones, help establish context. Dmitry does not like typing up long translations, but he is fairly happy going through a few pages (by telephone) with me and translating verbally.